# How to set null for DateTimePicker

Tags: datetime, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm using DateTimePicker([**@react-native-community/datetimepicker**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/datetimepicker)).

How to set null as default value for DateTimePicker?

Because in the first time , value of DateTimePicker should be null. When I set it to null ,get the following error :

> Invariant Violation: A date or time should be specified as 'value'.

```
 <DateTimePicker
     testID="dateTimePicker"
     timeZoneOffsetInMinutes={0}
     value={null}
     mode='date'
     is24Hour={true}
     display="default"
     onChange={onChange}
  />
```

Comment: I think that you have to choose a value that is a real date value. So just take todaysdate I guess...

Comment: It can't be null, just specify a default value if it's `null` like `value={this.state.time || new Date()}`

Comment: from the docs value should be  date not null ```<RNDateTimePicker value={new Date()} />```

Comment: The reason we need a `null` value is because defaulting to `new Date()` does not alone allow us to know if the user has actually selected a date or not.

Answer (score 3):

This post is a year old but I will answer to help other programmers.

You can initialize the state to null if the datepicker has not rendered in the page. You could have a state or hook that affects the visibility of your picker.

```
const [pickerVis, setPickerVis] = useState(false);
const [date, setDate] = useState(null);
```

Then with the use of a button/pressable/checkbox/Touchable etc you can use:

`onChange={() => { setDate(new Date()); setPickerVis(true)}}`

Then finally have an conditional render on the page like so:

```
{pickerVis === true && (<View><DateTimePicker
testID="dateTimePicker"
timeZoneOffsetInMinutes={0}
value={date}
mode='date'
is24Hour={true}
display="default"
onChange={onChange}
/> </View>)}
```

Comment: This will require two clicks just to show the dialog the first time.

Answer (score 1):

You should verify is your date is null on your onChange method

```
<DateTimePicker
        value={date}
        mode='date'
        onChange={(date) => {
            **if (date) setDate(date)** //This is your validation
            setShowDatePicker(false)
        }}
/>
```

Comment: did you validate it before you posting it as answer?

Comment: This does not prevent the error if the initial date value is null